# Is it possible to 'fill' a form like this?

Tags: django, forms, unit-testing, testing

I want to test a form. It is working, but the test doesn't.

One field of this form is popolated by a javascript function. I can use selenium to do so, but I don't want because it's giving problems and also I want isolate the test.

So I'm calling the form in my test, then I'm creating the choices (this is what javascript should do), then I'm setting the fields values.

My `models.py`:

```
class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('nome'), max_length=50, default='')
    namelanguage = models.ForeignKey(
        NameLanguage, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_language',
        verbose_name=_('linguaggio'), on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    nametype = models.ForeignKey(
        NameType, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_tipo',
        verbose_name=_('tipo'), on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    gender = models.ForeignKey(
       Gender, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_gender',
       verbose_name=_('sesso'), on_delete=models.PROTECT,
       blank=True, null=True)
    usato = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('usato'), default=0)
    approved = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = format_for_save_name(self.name)
        to_save = check_gender_name(self)
        if not to_save:
            return
        else:
            super(Name, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def format_for_save_name(name):
        myname = name.lower().strip()
        if myname[0] not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz#":
            myname = '#' + myname
        return myname
```

My `form.py`:

```
class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Name
        fields = ['namelanguage', 'nametype', 'gender', 'name', 'usato',
              'approved']
        widgets = {
            'gender': forms.RadioSelect(),
            'usato': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'approved': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

My `test_form.py`:

```
def test_form_validation(self):
    maschio = Gender.objects.create(name_en='Male', name_it='Maschio')
    nome = NameType.objects.create(name_en='Name', name_it='Nome')
    romani = NameLanguage.objects.create(
        name_en='Romans', name_it='Romani')
    romani.sintassi.add(nome)
    form = NameForm()
    form.fields['nametype'].disabled = False
    form.fields['nametype'].choices = [(nome.id, nome)]
    form.fields['nametype'].initial = nome.id
    form.fields['gender'].initial = maschio.id
    form.fields['name'].initial = 'Bill'
    form.fields['namelanguage'].initial = romani.id
    # form.fields['usato'].initial = 0
    # form.fields['approved'].initial = False
    print('1', form)
    # self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
    form.save()
```

`print('1', form)` gives a form without errors but `form.is_valid` is `False` and (when is commented out) `form.save()` gives an error when the model try to save the name field:

```
if myname[0] not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz#":
IndexError: string index out of range
```

That is because the name is an empty string and yet my `print('1', form)` gives all the fields with the right options selected and specifically the name field isn't empty but has `value="Bill"`:

```
<td><input type="text" name="name" value="Bill" maxlength="50" autofocus="" required id="id_name">
```

**Edit.** I tried to avoid that check and the problem is the same for the other fields: they looks ok on the `print('1', form)` but they don't arrive to the `form.save()`, for example in my `print('1', form)` I have:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_namelanguage">Linguaggio:</label></th><td><select name="namelanguage" required id="id_namelanguage">
 <option value="">---------</option>
 <option value="1" selected>Romani</option>
```

so it looks I have selected an option but then I receive this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: lists_name.namelanguage_id
```

Comment: why is this tagged unit testing?

Comment: The form is working, the test isn't, so the problem is something related to the test. Which kind of test? I'm trying to test my form and I want to keep the test isolated, so it's a unit test. Using Selenium it will becoming a functional test, for what I know (sorry, I'm newbie) because it involve the views, the template, the javascript, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why and how but this code is working:

```
def test_form_validation(self):
    maschio = Gender.objects.create(name_en='Male', name_it='Maschio')
    nome = NameType.objects.create(name_en='Name', name_it='Nome')
    romani = NameLanguage.objects.create(
        name_en='Romans', name_it='Romani')
    romani.syntax.add(nome)
    form = NameForm({'nametype': nome.id, 'gender': maschio.id,
                     'name': 'Remo', 'namelanguage': romani.id})
    form.fields['nametype'].initial = nome.id
    form.save()
    self.assertEqual(Name.objects.all().count(), 1)
    my_name = Name.objects.first()
    self.assertEqual(my_name.name, 'remo')
    self.assertEqual(my_name.nametype, nome)
    self.assertEqual(my_name.gender, maschio)
    self.assertEqual(my_name.namelanguage, romani)
```

Any comment will be appreciated