# Testing a form. What'happening? is this really working?

Tags: django, testing, django-forms

I have a django form with a field directed to a foreignkey. Initially is empty, I mean without any option. Javascript will add options based on another form field.

It's working but I want to test it, without using Selenium (and so, without using javascript).

After numerous [attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58652306/is-it-possible-to-fill-a-form-like-this) I write this code and apparently it's working but I don't know why and I'm not sure it's really working.

```
def test_form_validation(self):
    maschio = Gender.objects.create(name_en='Male', name_it='Maschio')
    nome = NameType.objects.create(name_en='Name', name_it='Nome')
    romani = NameLanguage.objects.create(
        name_en='Romans', name_it='Romani')
    romani.syntax.add(nome)
    form = NameForm({'nametype': nome.id, 'gender': maschio.id,
                     'name': 'Remo', 'namelanguage': romani.id})
    # print('1', form)
    form.fields['nametype'].initial = nome.id
    print('2', form)
    form.save()
    self.assertEqual(Name.objects.all().count(), 1)
    my_name = Name.objects.first()
    self.assertEqual(my_name.name, 'remo')
    self.assertEqual(my_name.nametype, nome)
    self.assertEqual(my_name.gender, maschio)
    self.assertEqual(my_name.namelanguage, romani)
    print('end of test')
```

`# print('1', form)` is commented out because with that the test will be give error on line `form.save()` (`ValueError: The Name could not be created because the data didn't validate.`). Without that line the test pass (!?!).

I will expected an error when I call my form bounded because `nametype` has no option to choose from. nome.id is not one of the ammissible choices. And in effect, as I said, it will give an error if I ask to print the form.

```
<tr><th><label for="id_nametype">Tipo:</label></th><td><select name="nametype" style="width:170px" disabled id="id_nametype">
  <option value="0">0</option>
</select></td></tr>
```

So, is this ok? and why it's working? what's happening?

Thank you

Edit

My `form.py`:

```
class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    form to add names to the database
    input: nothing
    output: the form
    """

    class Meta:
        model = Name
        fields = ['namelanguage', 'nametype', 'gender', 'name']
        widgets = {
            'gender': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }

    def clean_name(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['name'].lower()
        if data[0] not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            data = "#" + data
        return data

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            last_language = kwargs.get('initial')['namelanguage']
            last_nametype = kwargs.get('initial')['nametype']
            choices = get_nametype_choices(last_language)
            gender_variable = get_gender_variable(last_nametype)
        except (TypeError, KeyError):
            print('except nameform')
            choices = [(0, 0)]
            gender_variable = True
        super(NameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'autofocus': ''})
        self.fields['nametype'].widget.attrs.update({'style': 'width:170px'})
        self.fields['nametype'].choices = choices
        if choices[0][0] == 0:
            self.fields['nametype'].disabled = True
        if not gender_variable:
            print('gender non variable')
            self.fields['gender'].disabled = True
            self.fields['gender'].required = False
            try:
                self.fields['gender'].initial = Gender.objects.get(
                    name_it='neutro').id
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                self.fields['gender'].initial = None
        else:
            self.fields['gender'].disabled = False
            self.fields['gender'].required = True

def get_nametype_choices(last_language):
    """
    function called by NameForm__init__ to create the list of choices
    for nametype according to the language
    input: language
    output: a list of tuple with the appropriate nametype for the language
    """
    # print('get_nametype_choices')
    lista_file = []
    try:
        language = NameLanguage.objects.get(id=last_language)
        choices = language.syntax.all()
        for choice in choices:
            lista_file.append((choice.id, choice))
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        print('except get_nametype_choices')
        lista_file.append((0, 'Scegli il linguaggio'))
    return lista_file
```

`get_nametype_choices` is not called by the test because `last_language = kwargs.get('initial')['namelanguage']` in `NameForm.__init__` gives an exception.

Comment: First you need to show the definition of NameForm. Why wouldn't `nome.id` be one of the choices? Separately, I can't understand why you set all those initial values, especially as you do it *after* you have instantiated the form with the data parameter, so the initial values will be ignored.

Comment: If I don't set those initial values the test gives an error (ValueError: The Name could not be created because the data didn't validate.) when it arrives to form.save()

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok, I found out that I need only the first one